# Paperclip Video Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to enable video upload in my post. 
Can't get it to display the video. The video gets uploaded, I can confirm that while i manage to right click on the video area and download it. The problem is how to view it correctly.

**Migration:**

```
class AddAttachmentVideoToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :posts do |t|
      t.attachment :video
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :posts, :video
  end
end
 def change
    create_table :videos do |t|
        t.string :video_file_name
        t.string :video_content_type
        t.integer :video_file_size
        t.datetime :video_updated_at

        t.timestamps
    end
end
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope :order => 'created_at desc'
    attr_accessible :content, :title, :photo, :photo_delete, :video, :video_delete, :dependent => :destroy
    has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {  :thumb => "600x600#", :medium => "300x300#", :small => "160x160#"}
    has_attached_file :video
    validates_uniqueness_of :title
    validates_presence_of :title, :content
    has_destroyable_file :photo, :video
end
```

**Video part in my post _form**

```
<div class="visible-md visible-lg">
  <%= f.file_field :video, :style => "float: left;" %>
  <%= f.check_box :video_delete, :style => "float: left;" %> &nbsp;Delete video
  </div><br />
<div class="visible-xs">
  <%= f.file_field :video, :style => "center" %>
  <%= f.check_box :video_delete, :style => "center" %> &nbsp;Delete video
</div><br />
```

Video part in Post Show

```
<% if @post.video? %>
<h1 class="center">
<%= @post.title %>
</h1><br />
<%= video_path @post.video.url %>       
<% end %>
```

I have also tried with video_tag which don't work and when I try with:

```
<iframe width="490" height="275" src="<%= video_path @post.video.url %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen autoplay="true">
            </iframe>
```

I get a player that won't play.
Would really appreciate if you look it through and maybe help me to come up with a solution that will work. Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what you want. Keep in mind hosting your own user uploaded videos has some problems. Like you making sure to get the proper encodings for cross browser compatibility.
http://jplayer.org/ is great open source player that will take care of your view layer. If you want high cross browser compatibility you will need to supply the jplayer with paths to multiple encodings. You can use a service like zen coder. This does get pretty expensive but they all have some level of free development account to learn and experiment with their system.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try the jplayer out :)

Comment: @TyrelRichey I've Installed jplayer, loaded the skin and now have a video player shell. But I don't now how to call the video so the player works. I have this jquery:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4v: "<%= link_to @post.video.url %>",
          });
        },
        swfPath: "/assets/jplayer",
        supplied: "m4v"
      });
    });
  </script>

Comment: Got the example video to play, this means that it loads the all the installed files. Though It won't play my vid when i call m4v: "<% link_to @post.video.url %>"

Comment: What is the output of Post.first.video.url in the console?

Comment: Using ffmpeg,  the video is successfully uploaded but i cant figure out how to call the video in my view and play it..

Comment: anyone give me the link of uploading video using paperclip. waiting for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `video` tag, not `iframe` (only `video` tag has autoplay options). Check here what formats are supported by what browser: http://caniuse.com/#search=video

If you want crossbrowser solution, try VideoJS - http://www.videojs.com/
Here you can get a Rails plugin - https://github.com/seanbehan/videojs_rails

Comment: Thanks, yeah used videojs. Not the gem though :P ffmpeg, paperclip and flashplayer was the best solution to get it working smooth in every Webb-browser!

Comment: I use https://github.com/devthenet/voyeur with Sidekiq to convert videos in background.

Answer (score 3):

**Paperclip Video Upload:**

I had the same issue just this past week - Try this!

```
Video model:
    has_attached_file :video, styles: {
        :medium => {
          :geometry => "640x480",
          :format => 'mp4'
        },
        :thumb => { :geometry => "160x120", :format => 'jpeg', :time => 10}
    }, :processors => [:transcoder]
    validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
```

Make sure you already bundled:

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg", "~> 1.2.0"
```

Run the paperclip migration:

```
rails g paperclip model video
```

Be sure to add in post_controller.rb:

```
private

    def bscenes_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:video)
    end
```

Upload form:

```
<%= f.file_field :video %>
```

Show page:

```
<%= video_tag bscene.video.url(:medium), controls: true, style: "max-width: 100%;" %>
```

At this point you should get this error:

```
Av::UnableToDetect (Unable to detect any supported library):
```

Go to your terminal and type in:

```
brew options ffmpeg
```

Then run the following to install ffmpeg:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools
```

**Restart your server and try to upload a video now! Hope this helps - Happy coding :)**