# Video playback with paperclip rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, paperclip

I'm wanting to set up video uploads so that users can view and play them back. I'm new to rails dose any one know how this can be done?

Comment: Set up like others files (follow Paperclip documentation), and use [video_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-video_tag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

In the model that will contain the video you will need the right format (`ffmpeg`) and validation for videos:

```
   has_attached_file :attachment,
          styles: lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? {:small => "x200>", :medium => "x300>", :large => "x400>"}  : {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}, :medium => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}}},
          :processors => lambda { |a| a.is_video? ? [ :ffmpeg ] : [ :thumbnail ] }
    validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
```

Update from comment:

```
 has_attached_file :video, styles: {
    :medium => {
      :geometry => "640x480",
      :format => 'mp4'
    },
    :thumb => { :geometry => "160x120", :format => 'jpeg', :time => 10}
  }, :processors => [:transcoder]
```

Comment: So generating the rails generate paperclip post attachment then adding above in the model/post.rb file / then adding :attachment in the post_params / then for the views <%= video_tag post.attachment.url(:medium), controls: true, type: "video/mp4", size: "612x612" %>

Comment: ffmpeg has depreciated so I'm using paperclip-av-transcoder

Comment: Thanks! - Locally I'm getting a black video screen but the video play button is clickable but dose nothing - Im thinking maybe its because in need ffmpeg loaded or a video converter?

Comment: Yes you might need a converter or at least crossbrowser solutions. Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222492/paperclip-video-upload

Comment: Do i have to add both of these has_attached_file options or just one?

Comment: I see only 1 has_attached_file. Which other one are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

There's some live code to achieve this [here](https://github.com/joehilton/hpvideos/blob/master/app/models/attachment.rb):

```
#Gemfile
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg", "~> 1.2.0"

#app/models/attachment.rb
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_attached_file :attachment,
        styles: {:thumb => { geometry: "100x100#", format: 'jpg', time: 10}, medium: { gemometry: "300x300#", format: 'jpg', time: 10}},
        processors: [ :ffmpeg ]

end
```

---

The main issue you have with this is something call [preprocessing](http://rushabhhathi.in/2012/04/30/preprocessing-in-paperclip/).

When you upload any attachment with Paperclip, it has to process it before storing it. The processing converts to the correct format and resizes it (you can do other cool things with it as well).

Video processing is slightly different than image processing, in that you first have to get the video processed so your server can play it back, and then you also have to lift some screenshots out of it.

Thus, you need a custom processor, which @Czanfar posted in his answer is either going to be a choice between `ffmpeg` or `transcoder`

---

I have also written an answer to this here:
[Rails video uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491643/rails-video-uploading)

---

By the way, here's when I went to see the guys who made Paperclip:

[image]

Comment: Thanks bud, it was in Stockholm

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Cyzanfars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3307520/cyzanfar) answer I got it working!

> Make sure you install ffmpeg

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools
```